# How can I write this query correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

How can I write a query that gives the country name, city, postal code, street address and the number of departments where at least 2 employees work? Below is the query I wrote, but I get "not a GROUP BY expression" error as a result of the query.

```
SELECT k.COUNTRY_NAME,
       l.CITY,
       l.POSTAL_CODE,
       l.STREET_ADDRESS,
       e.DEPARTMENT_ID,
       COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID)
FROM hr.employees e
    JOIN hr.departments c
        ON (c.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID)
    JOIN hr.locations l
        ON (c.LOCATION_ID = l.LOCATION_ID)
    JOIN hr.countries k
        ON (k.COUNTRY_ID = l.COUNTRY_ID)
GROUP BY e.DEPARTMENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) > 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all **non-aggregated** columns(`c.country_name`,`l.city`,`l.postal_code`,`l.street_address`,`e.department_id`) should be listed within the `GROUP BY` list which is not suitable for your case. Rather use `COUNT(.) OVER (..)` analytic function with `PARTITION BY e.department_id` option in order to group by `department_id` column  such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT c.country_name,
           l.city,
           l.postal_code,
           l.street_address,
           e.department_id,
           COUNT(e.employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY e.department_id) AS count 
      FROM hr.employees e
      JOIN hr.departments d
        ON d.department_id = e.department_id
      JOIN hr.locations l
        ON d.location_id = l.location_id
      JOIN hr.countries c
        ON c.country_id = l.country_id
    )
   WHERE count >= 2 -- equality is added considering "at least" 2
   ORDER BY count
```

Btw, the parentheses next to the `ON` clause are redundant

Answer (score 0):

You would first get the set of all departments that have at least 2 employees as follows(atleast_two)

After that you would join the data with the rest of your query and pull the attributes of interest.

```
with atleast_two
  as (select c.DEPARTMENT_ID
            ,count(employee_id) as cnt_employees
        from hr.employees e 
        join hr.departments c 
          on (c.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID) 
        group by c.deptid
        having count(employee_id)>2
      )
    select k.COUNTRY_NAME
          , l.CITY
          , l.POSTAL_CODE
          , l.STREET_ADDRESS
          , e.DEPARTMENT_ID
          , c.cnt_employees
      from hr.employees e 
      join atleast_two c 
        on (c.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID) 
      join hr.locations l 
        on (c.LOCATION_ID=l.LOCATION_ID) 
      join hr.countries k 
        on (k.COUNTRY_ID=l.COUNTRY_ID);
```